# Why are two decimals with the same value formatted differently

Tags: c#, decimal, tostring

I have two little pieces of code. In my opinion, they should result in the same string, but they don't:

```
(1.23M * 100M).ToString()
```

results in:

```
123,00
```

and

```
(123M).ToString()
```

results in:

```
123
```

My very simple question is: can somebody explain me why this (strange?) behavior happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're two different values, bitwise. Unlike `double`, `decimal` does not automatically normalize - it looks like it's retained the information that at one point you had two decimal places. You can see the exact same difference without the multiplication:

```
Console.WriteLine(123m)
Console.WriteLine(123.00m);
```

The documentation is somewhat unclear (from what I can see) about exactly how the result of operations on `decimal` values is performed, in terms of how many decimal places are retained. (I wouldn't be surprised to learn that it's standardised somewhere...)

Comment: There is documentation on that, but unfortunately the actual behavior does not 100% match the spec.

Answer (score 4):

The `decimal` type is represented by an integer scaled by a factor of 10. From the documentation for `decimal`:

> The scaling factor also preserves any trailing zeros in a Decimal number. Trailing zeros do not affect the value of a Decimal number in arithmetic or comparison operations. However, trailing zeros might be revealed by the ToString method if an appropriate format string is applied.

Using `GetBits` you can see that `123.00M` is represented as 12300 / 10<sup>2</sup> while `123M` is 123 / 10<sup>0</sup>.

**Edit**

I took a simple program that demostrates the issue:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((1.23M * 100M).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine((123M).ToString());
    }

}
```

I looked at the generated IL:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       51 (0x33)
  .maxstack  6
  .locals init ([0] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal CS$0$0000)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4     0x300c
  IL_0006:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0007:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0008:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0009:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_000a:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.Decimal::.ctor(int32,
                                                                     int32,
                                                                     int32,
                                                                     bool,
                                                                     uint8)
  IL_000f:  stloc.0
  IL_0010:  ldloca.s   CS$0$0000
  IL_0012:  call       instance string [mscorlib]System.Decimal::ToString()
  IL_0017:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_001c:  nop
  IL_001d:  ldc.i4.s   123
  IL_001f:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.Decimal::.ctor(int32)
  IL_0024:  stloc.0
  IL_0025:  ldloca.s   CS$0$0000
  IL_0027:  call       instance string [mscorlib]System.Decimal::ToString()
  IL_002c:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0031:  nop
  IL_0032:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

We can see that the compiler actually optimized away the multiplication and inserted a call to a construct a single decimal instance for the first case. The two instances are using different representations. They are basically what I described above.